# Reordering Jordan Matrix Sub-Blocks

Tags: matrices, jordan-normal-form

Let $J$ and $K$ be $n × n$ Jordan matrices which can be made equal after a reordering of sub-blocks.
Show that $J= S^{-1}KS$ by explaining how to construct $S$.

I understand that these two matrices are similar because changing the order of sub-blocks preserves geometric and algebraic multiplicity of the shared eigenvalues, so we simply have to rearrange those blocks to change between Jordan matrices. However, I don't know how to actually construct the invertible matrix that would accomplish this reordering.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It’s not different from the general case. If you know K and J thus you can calculate S by linear system.

Here is a simple example:

[Find the jordan basis for $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541931/find-the-jordan-basis-for-a/2541946)

Comment: I understand how to construct the Jordan form for a given matrix, however in this question we are given two matrices that are already in Jordan form and asked to determine the invertible matrix that can be used to show that they are similar.

Comment: If you know both J and K, you can proceed solving JS^{-1}=KS^{-1}.

Comment: Ahhh that does help clear up the relation between ideas. Thank you! Do you know if this concept can be generalized in a simple manner given that J and K are Jordan Matrices? I feel like the question is asking for a specific quick algorithm to generate S, given that J and K are block diagonal.

Comment: Of course since J and K are block matrices exists some algorithm to solve in a more efficient manner the linear system, thats a matter of numerical calculation, but I'm not expert about it.

Comment: Okay! Thank you for the guidance

Comment: Thanks if you are ok please set as solved, if you consider solved and upvote please :)

Comment: Not really capable of upvoting yet, it doesn't show up in the system. Just created this account. I'll set as solved :) but if anyone has any extra help on that algorithm please let me know!

Comment: @Kayto Ok, Thank you!